# OpenCV.JS cv.Sift is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs, opencv

I'm working in a project with opencvjs and angularjs. I need to apply homography algorithm but when I create a Sift object, the console shows this error

> TypeError: cv.Sift is not a constructor

Can somebody assist to tell me how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you share some code causing that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until OpenCV.js is compiled: `cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{ doSomethingWithOpenCV() }`